# Is it possible have logging module fix line ends when writing to a log

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using the logging modules to write strings to a log file.  Is it possible to have all line endings converted to '\n'.  My output from various places might have \r or \r\n and I want everything written to the log to have consistent line endings.  Something like this:

```
class Logger():
    def __init__( self, path ):
        msgFormat   = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d\t%(message)s'
        dateFormat  = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        logging.basicConfig( format=msgFormat, datefmt=dateFormat, filename=path, level=logging.INFO )

    def Log ( self, theStr ):
        logging.info( str( theStr ))
```

Then I create a logger with a valid path and the output from Pexpect looks something like this b'Line One\r\nLine Two'.  So I decode() it and send it to Log( )

```
result = b'Line One\r\nLine Two'
theLog.Log( result.decode( ))
```

Comment: I haven't used `logging` very much but I would have expected that universal newlines would apply here. Could you post a [mre]?

Comment: I didn't post an example since it would be a rather large one.  I'm using Pexcept.  The result coming back from CLI output has /r/n at the end of each line.  When I write the returned block out using the logging module I end up with empty lines between each line.  I never open the file myself.  I just use logging.basicConfig() to setup the log file and start writing to the file.  basicConfig() doesn't accept newline as a named parameter.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking this but it isn't that hard to make a handler that takes multi-line messages and splits them so each line is printed with the log prefix.  If you wanted to split with universal newlines that would work as well

Comment: @Cireo I am aware that universal newlines 'should' take care of it BUT I don't see a method, using logging, to pass down my setting for newlines.  So I am not sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding your own Formatter. At this point it's probably easier to not use basicConfig anymore because we need to do non-basic things. The log lines will all end in `\n` because that is the default terminator that FileHandler uses. If you want something else add `handler.terminator='\r\n'` or whatever lineendings are preferred.

```
import logging

class NewLineFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        msg = super().format(record)
        return msg.rstrip() # removes trailing newlines (and other whitespace)

class Logger():
    def __init__(self, path):
        msgFormat   = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d\t%(message)s'
        dateFormat  = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(path)
        handler.setFormatter(NewLineFormatter(msgFormat, dateFormat))
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.logger = logger

    def Log(self, the_str):
        self.logger.info(the_str)

l = Logger('test.log')
l.Log('test\r\n')
```

Comment: I'm at home but I'll take a look at this when I get to work.  Only a good solution if a string such as this works:  'test\r\ntest\r\ntest\r\n'.

Comment: that string will be logged as `test\r\ntest\r\ntest\n`. It only removes it at the end. That is what `rstrip()` does, but any logic can be put at that line. Edit: it should be rather easy to change it to whatever you need.

Comment: e.g. `'\n'.join(msg.splitlines())`

Comment: @blues I was thinking about this on the way to work and how is this any better then just calling self.logger.info(theStr.replace())?  What you want is to take all 3 styles of line endings and make them into one style.  (\r\n and \r and \n into say \n).  Interesting Cireo's response just showed up after I submitted the above.  I'd expect the same to be true though.

Comment: @Cireo Yep that is simple and better since it handles all 3 styles.  if msg = 'aaa\r\nbbb\rccc\nddd' then '\n'.join(msg.splitlines()) returns 'aaa\nbbb\nccc\nddd'.  Of course better then replace() since that would only handle one type.  TY!!  Oh and NewLineFormatter is not required then.

Comment: @Keith in your specific scenario this is better because: it runs after the builtin formatter and it's easier to supply it with arbitrary logic without running any danger of destroying possible formatting in the message string. Also beyond your specific example, the wrapper you are creating around logger isn't really necessary. You could just remove that whole class and have cleaner code.

Comment: @blues  I have a class so I can have a single logger in my entire project.  My project is some 80k lines now so I have created the class so I can objectify the logger and hang two loggers off of another lower level class.  My two log files with different styles of strings. One for run detail and the other for debug strings.  So this is 'cleaner' for me.